# MongoDB FindAndModify dependent on document field/value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document similar to this:

```
{
     ...
     "LastAccess" : "2012-09-19T05:47:45.982Z", // Time of last document access
     "Expires" : "2012-09-19T06:47:45.982Z", // Time this document expires
     "MaxAge" : 3600, // Seconds to live
}
```

I believe the only safe way to accomplish what I want to is FindAndModify, so my question is, I want to update the **LastAccess** to the Current UTC Time (this is obviously easy), but then I want to update the **Expires** by the **LastAccess** + **MaxAge** where MaxAge can be different on a document to document basis.

In short, is there anyway to update a field in a document (in this case Expires) while it is dependent on another field on the document, in one FindAndModify call?

Comment: why not calculate the "Expires" on the fly based on the other two values? It really makes little or no sense to store a product of another two values into the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use existing fields in the document within the update query.  Here are a few options.

### Time to live collections:

You can use a time to live collection if you want to delete the document when it expires.  In time to live collections, documents are automatically deleted after a specified duration, which means you can eliminate the "Expires" and "MaxAge" fields entirely.

Create the TTL index with a 30 second lifetime:

```
mongos> db.last.ensureIndex({ "LastAccess" : 1 }, { "expireAfterSeconds" : 30 })
```

Insert our documents:

```
mongos> db.last.insert({ "Value" : "No Expiration" })
mongos> db.last.insert({ "Value" : "Expiration", "LastAccess": new Date() })
mongos> db.last.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505d15ac283b060dbc637ec0"), "Value" : "No Expiration" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505d15b1283b060dbc637ec1"), "Value" : "Expiration", "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-22T01:34:41.102Z") }
```

Sleep for 15 seconds:

```
mongos> sleep(15000)
null
mongos> db.last.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505d15ac283b060dbc637ec0"), "Value" : "No Expiration" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505d15b1283b060dbc637ec1"), "Value" : "Expiration", "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-22T01:34:41.102Z") }
```

Update our access time:

```
mongos> db.last.update({ "Value" : "Expiration" }, { "$set" : { "LastAccess" : new Date() }})
mongos> sleep(15000)
null
```

Both documents are still around:

```
mongos> db.last.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505d15ac283b060dbc637ec0"), "Value" : "No Expiration" }
{ "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-22T01:35:07.629Z"), "Value" : "Expiration", "_id" : ObjectId("505d15b1283b060dbc637ec1") }
```

Sleep for 30 seconds:

```
mongos> sleep(30000)
null
```

Now only our document without an expiration is around:

```
mongos> db.last.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505d15ac283b060dbc637ec0"), "Value" : "No Expiration" }
```

Note that the process that deletes the documents only runs [once per minute](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#constraints), so the time something is deleted may be up to a minute after its actual expiration date.

### Two find and modify calls:

Insert a document with the required values:

```
mongos> db.last.insert({"Value":"oldvalue","LastAccess":new Date(),"Expires":new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 3200),"MaxAge":3200,InProgress:false})
mongos> db.last.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505b89292271f63498810600"), "Value" : "oldvalue", "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:22:49.637Z"), "Expires" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:22:52.837Z"), "MaxAge" : 3200, "InProgress" : false }
```

Modify the InProgress field to warn others that we are looking at the MaxAge
field (if you don't care if someone changes the MaxAge field while you are doing
this, you don't need the InProgress field and you can just do a find on this
step):

```
mongos> doc = db.last.findAndModify({ "query" : { "Value" : "oldvalue", "InProgress" : false }, "update" : { "$set" : { "InProgress" : true } } });
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505b89292271f63498810600"),
    "Value" : "oldvalue",
    "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:22:49.637Z"),
    "Expires" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:22:52.837Z"),
    "MaxAge" : 3200,
    "InProgress" : false
}
mongos> db.last.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("505b89292271f63498810600"), "Value" : "oldvalue", "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:22:49.637Z"), "Expires" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:22:52.837Z"), "MaxAge" : 3200, "InProgress" : true }
```

Actually update the document with the new expiration date, and set InProgress to false to mark that we are no longer looking at MaxAge:

```
mongos> db.last.findAndModify({ "query" : { "Value" : "oldvalue", "InProgress" : true }, "update" : { "$set" : { "Value" : "newvalue", "LastAccess" : new Date(), "Expires" : new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + doc.MaxAge), "InProgress" : false } }, "new" : true });
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505b89292271f63498810600"),
    "Value" : "newvalue",
    "LastAccess" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:23:29.058Z"),
    "Expires" : ISODate("2012-09-20T21:23:32.258Z"),
    "MaxAge" : 3200,
    "InProgress" : false
}
```

### db.eval():

db.eval() could also be used here, but should be avoided for [performance reasons](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Limitationsof{{eval}})

Comment: Brilliant. Was not aware of the TTL feature. Thanks!